# How can I ensure Spring constructs a bean once

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have a complex enterprise environment with multiple projects depending on each other. Configuration is handled by spring and includes crazy number imports and what not.

Looks like by default Spring is OK with constructing a bean with the same name more than once. Particularly, in case of multiple Spring contexts. Each context its own instance of the same singleton bean. Singleton is not really a singleton in Spring architects' minds...

Unfortunately, in my case there's a bean that can never be created more than once.

Is there a way to enforce Spring checking upon the bean whether it's been created already and not to try to call its constructor again?

Particularly, the bean creates ehcache's CacheManager inside and fails because CacheManager with the same name can't be created twice.

```
    <bean id="cacheService" class="somepackage.CacheServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="/somepackage/ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>
```

I don't have control over the CacheServiceImpl code. I can only change configuration around it.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Spring will by default treat beans as singletons.

Comment: If it's not declared as `prototype` it should already be a singleton.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. It may be true for a single Spring context, but it's probably happening due to multiple Spring contexts created and each is trying to create that poor bean.

Comment: if you have placed 2-3 times the auto package scan in every context that you are referring , then every context , load the same bean as singleton , so try to put it or in the global configuration package so it would be visible everywhere and be loaded at startup , either place it in a custom context which will be applied only when needed , in a custom package/project

Comment: I smell some serious problem with spring configuration in your project. Maybe it requires refactoring ?

Comment: How do I control the number of contexts Spring creates? I don't see anything in the code that would trigger that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out finally. The reason for loading the context twice was a hidden error occurring during the first context loading. A long and boring explanation below.

Context is supposed to be loaded during first invocation of spring method DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext().

There's a class DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate, which is responsible for actual loading the context once and caching it for future uses. The method code is below:

```
@Override
public ApplicationContext loadContext(MergedContextConfiguration mergedContextConfiguration) {
    synchronized (this.contextCache) {
        ApplicationContext context = this.contextCache.get(mergedContextConfiguration);
        if (context == null) {
            try {
                context = loadContextInternal(mergedContextConfiguration);
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug(String.format("Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [%s]",
                            mergedContextConfiguration));
                }
                this.contextCache.put(mergedContextConfiguration, context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load ApplicationContext", ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(String.format("Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [%s]",
                        mergedContextConfiguration));
            }
        }

        this.contextCache.logStatistics();

        return context;
    }
}
```

Obviously, when a Throwable other than Exception gets thrown during loadContextInternal() invocation, the application context doesn't get put in the cache.

Apparently, even when a single JUnit test is run getApplicationContext() method is called more than once with an expectation that second time it won't need to be loaded again since already cached.

If an Error is thrown during first load it gets buried and JUnit/Spring continues with the test until it calls getApplicationContext() for the second time. That's where it catches the exception and crashes because ehcache's doesn't expect CacheManager to be initialized more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Different Spring application contexts don't know about each other. As far as each context is concerned, your object *is* a singleton. However, it sounds like you don't want there to be multiple contexts.

How are you creating contexts? Your application should create a single instance of `ApplicationContext` (probably in `main` or somewhere nearby). Anything else that needs an application context should have it injected or be made `ApplicationContextAware`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation

You mention a "complex enterprise environment". What's worked best for us where I work is having a single project manage Spring. Assuming all your projects are being run in the same application (otherwise Spring can't really help you), there's likely some project that starts everything off.  For us, that's the project that is built into a war and deployed to our server.